# How to get compatibility version in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

When configuring services within MVC app you can set the compatibility version:

```
services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
```

How can I retrieve this version later in my own code to determine which compatibility version is in use?

There does not appear to be a corresponding GetCompatibilityVersion method anywhere and google/stackoverflow search was not my friend.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps you can store it explicitly in your Startup class based on the logic required? Then you can just pass that field to the `SetCompatibilityVersion`.

Comment: I have a workaround method in mind which involves storing it, just doesn't seem like the "proper" way at the mo, if there is no official way i will look at that, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MVC compatibility version is actually stored in an instance of a class called `MvcCompatibilityOptions`. You can retrieve this object by locating it through the IoC container that is being used by the application – either ASP.NET Core's built-in one or a third party one.

For example, with the default IoC, you can retrieve it like this:

```
var compatibilityVersion = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IOptions<MvcCompatibilityOptions>>().Value.CompatibilityVersion;
```

`app` is an instance of `IApplicationBuilder`.